# DefaultDecryptorWithMAC throws exception "cannot decrypt message with this passphrase"

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, encryption, crypto++

I'm experiencing the exact same issue as [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.cryptopp/2518).  Want to encrypt on Ubuntu (VM guest) and decrypt on Windows (host).

In this case, because I'm using DefaultEncryptorWithMAC with AES-256, I 
get the exception "cannot decrypt message with this passphrase".

**EDIT**

A buildable example: [this](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/DefaultEncryptorWithMAC) slightly modified.  Ubuntu guest:

```
//$ cat > secret-message.txt
//Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ofstream;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <cryptopp/default.h>
using CryptoPP::DefaultEncryptorWithMAC;
using CryptoPP::DefaultDecryptorWithMAC;

#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::HashFilter;

#include <cryptopp/files.h>
using CryptoPP::FileSource;
using CryptoPP::FileSink;

#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
using CryptoPP::SHA1;

#define UNUSED(x) (void(x))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc); UNUSED(argv);

    std::locale l("");
    cout << "Locale: " << l.name() << endl;

    string password = "super secret password";
    string encrypted, decrypted;
    ofstream ofs("./secret-message-enc.txt", ofstream::binary);

    cout << "Password: " << password << endl;

    FileSource fs1("./secret-message.txt", true,
            new DefaultEncryptorWithMAC(
                (byte*)password.data(), password.size(),
                new HexEncoder(
                    new StringSink(encrypted)
                    )
                )
            );

    cout << "Encrypted: " << encrypted << endl;

    ofs << encrypted;

    SHA1 hash;
    string digest;

    StringSource ss1(encrypted, true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(digest))));

    cout << "SHA1: " << digest << endl;

    StringSource ss(encrypted, true,
            new HexDecoder(
                new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(
                    (byte*)password.data(), password.size(),
                    new StringSink(decrypted)
                    )
                )
            );

    cout << "Decrypted: " << decrypted << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
Locale: en_CA.UTF-8
Password: super secret password
Encrypted: 9B6F165AE9491B477E0E8E1CE23BE735242303078D246C8D6828BFC5D047B30BDBFC929ACAD30E97A94708BA4B36B24120A42AB53366C4FA8E68087E659F4CB9206E519BCB5C9551C775723DA2BADFF3903D27CBA1914B3E7403F9D59121587A83D434C4A84DB40A27E5FC19C3F7FF2E
SHA1: 7D2043DE8B51B20810B18026F5318EDDC1EF9196
Decrypted: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
```

Transfer `secret-message-enc.txt` to Windows host.  VS2013 compiled with UNICODE project setting:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "default.h"
using CryptoPP::DefaultDecryptorWithMAC;

#include "filters.h"
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::HashFilter;

#include "files.h"
using CryptoPP::FileSource;

#include "hex.h"
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

#include "sha.h"
using CryptoPP::SHA1;

#define UNUSED(x) (void(x))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc); UNUSED(argv);

    std::locale l("");
    cout << "Locale: " << l.name() << endl;

    string password = "super secret password";
    string encrypted, decrypted;
    ifstream ifs("./secret-message-enc.txt", ifstream::binary);

    cout << "Password: " << password << endl;

    ifs >> encrypted;
    cout << "Encrypted: " << encrypted << endl;

    SHA1 hash;
    string digest;

    FileSource fs1("./secret-message-enc.txt", true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(digest))));

    cout << "SHA1: " << digest << endl;

    try
    {
        FileSource fs2("./secret-message-enc.txt", true,
                new HexDecoder(
                    new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(
                        (byte*)password.data(), password.size(),
                            new StringSink(decrypted)
                    )
                )
            );

        cout << "Decrypted: " << decrypted << endl;
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Gives,

```
Locale: English_United States.1252
Password: super secret password
Encrypted: 9B6F165AE9491B477E0E8E1CE23BE735242303078D246C8D6828BFC5D047B30BDBFC929ACAD30E97A94708BA4B36B24120A42AB53366C4FA8E68087E659F4CB9206E519BCB5C9551C775723DA2BADFF3903D27CBA1914B3E7403F9D59121587A83D434C4A84DB40A27E5FC19C3F7FF2E
SHA1: 7D2043DE8B51B20810B18026F5318EDDC1EF9196
DefaultDecryptor: cannot decrypt message with this passphrase
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: could the passphrase contain non ascii characters? If it does its internal representation will be different in windows (win1252 or CP850) and Ubuntu (UTF-8).

Comment: Consider posting a complete buildable example that reproduces the problem. If you want anyone to look at your problem, that is.

Comment: Another possible source of error: how to you *transport* the crypted file from one system to the other one? You should take a hash (md5 or sha1) on one system and compare it on the other.

Comment: A key: "byte size is smaller in Ubuntu". If you provide the same fully specified (full correct length) inputs the same output will be produced. Hex dump the inputs to find the error.

Comment: Different systems will have different defaults.  You should avoid **all** defaults and explicitly specify everything.  Crypto is designed to fail if things do not match exactly, so even a small incompatibility can disrupt everything.  If you are using a passphrase, then explicitly specify the byte translation: UTF-8 or UTF-16; BOM or no BOM; BE or LE.  Any of those might cause an incompatibility.

Comment: @rossum Makes sense and looking into that. Explicit encoding is new to me.  Can you suggest how to do that with the above example?  My program extensively uses `std::string` (and proxy string class).  Thanks.

Comment: 6 Years later and I have the same issue... unbelievable.